# AJAX Submit Form and Time Without Refresh

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a simple form that submits some data to a Google Sheet via AJAX, this is working successfully.

I need to send the current time. The `time` value *does* send, but unless the page is refreshed, it remains the same.

Presumably because I am using PHP in order to store the `time` and `date` in hidden inputs, and these values won't update until I refresh the page.

I'm unable to refresh the page, it must remain static.

How can I store the `date` and `time` values as real-time and send with the AJAX?

My code is below;

HTML / PHP

```
<form id="feedbackFormGood" name="feedbackFormGood">
    <input hidden="true" name="Feedback" type="text" value="GOOD"> 
    <input hidden="true" name="Date" type="text" value="<?php echo date('j/n/Y'); ?>"> 
    <input hidden="true" name="Time" type="text" value="<?php echo date('H:i:s'); ?>"> 
    <input src="images/feedback/happy.png" type="image">
</form>
```

AJAX

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var request;
    $("#feedbackFormGood").submit(function(event)
    {
        event.preventDefault();
        var $form = $(this);
        var $inputs = $form.find("input, select, button, textarea");
        var serializedData = $form.serialize();
        request = $.ajax(
        {
            url: "MyURL", // this is a Google Sheet
            type: "post",
            data: serializedData
        });
    });
});
```

Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: Dont pass time, you can get the exact time in MyURL page. And will be the same time the ajax will process.

Comment: If you need the current time in PHP, Why not just use the date function in your PHP code, in your current use case there is no need for the date in js if you want to send the current time

Comment: Why not generate the time and date using javascript? Or if you have access to the code on MyURL get the time and date there

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try adding the date and time using JavaScript

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var request;
    $("#feedbackFormGood").submit(function(event)
    {
        event.preventDefault();
        var today = new Date();
        var date = today.getDate()+'/'+(today.getMonth()+1)+'/'+today.getFullYear();
        var time = today.getHours() + ":" + today.getMinutes() + ":" + today.getSeconds()
        var $form = $(this);
        var $inputs = $form.find("input, select, button, textarea");
        var serializedData = $form.serialize();
        request = $.ajax(
        {
            url: "MyURL", // this is a Google Sheet
            type: "post",
            data: serializedData + '&Date=' + date + '&Time=' + time
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Sorry the variables need to be in the submit block my fault. Updated the answer.

Comment: Peftect - just what I wanted. Thank you :)

Answer (score -2):

You can use php inbuilt function "now()" to insert the date time in database...
Use this in insert query while inserting the data in database, don't try to pass the date time from form or ajax.
you can write code at server side to store date and time regular intervals.

Comment: what you want exactly, you are trying to store date time on request or else?

Comment: you can use jquery to get date and time but its better to code on server side....